# .htaccess Appends .php to URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My intention with the following code (specifically `RewriteRule ^s/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]`) is for the URL

```
example.com/s/full-name
```

to work as if it were

```
example.com/index?s=full-name
```

Currently, my server is allowing me to use the URL-style `example.com/s/$1`, but it isn't displaying the content that can be found at `index?s=full-name`. Instead, it's changing the URL to

```
example.com/s/full-name.php/
```

when `example.com/s/full-name` is requested and I have no idea why. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^s/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 400 /index?err=400
ErrorDocument 401 /index?err=401
ErrorDocument 403 /index?err=403
ErrorDocument 404 /index?err=404 
ErrorDocument 500 /index?err=500
```

Comment: You don't have the `R` flag so it shouldn't redirect. If you put `exit;` at the top of `index.php` does it still redirect? Because maybe PHP is doing the redirect, not `.htaccess`.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same results even with `exit;` at the top of `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

First, your conditions are wrong in the index routing command. The second thing is you have a rule that appends php to the end of your request but it does so without checking to see if the php file exists. Try reordering the rules and fix the conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^s/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help. I re-ordered the commands as per your suggstions: the 301 first, then the index route, then the .php drop, and then the error pages, but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Jon, did that and the result is different. Server is now allowing me to go to `example.com/s/$1` without showing a 404 or appending .php, but it's not displaying the contents of `index.php?s=$1`. This result is the same whether $1 exists as a possible value of `$_GET['s']` or not.

Comment: I don't have an `/s` directory or a '$1' file on the server anywhere, so it's not a negotiations issue.